# Automatic method selection based on class instance

Tags: c++, oop, downcast

I have two variants of the same method. I also have an instance of a base class type, but I don't know what specific class it is an instance of. I now want to automatically select the appropriate method depending on the actual type of the object. It seems impossible though and the only solution I can come up with is to check all possibilities by casting.
There has to be a nicer solution though.

Here is my minimal example:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class A
{
public:    
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "B.bar()" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A
{
public:    
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "C.bar()" << std::endl;
    }    
};

class Z
{
public:
    Z(int variable) : m_variable(variable) {};

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<B> b)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(B) method! " << m_variable << std::endl;
        b->bar();
    }

    void foo(std::shared_ptr<C> c)
    {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(C) method!" << m_variable << std::endl;
        c->bar();
    }
private:
  int m_variable;
};


int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> b(new B());

  Z z(42);

  //z.foo(b); // This doesn't work

  // But this does
  std::shared_ptr<B> b_cast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<B>(b);
  if (b_cast.get())
    z.foo(b_cast);
}
```

http://cpp.sh/9fqne

At the moment I have to resort to dynamic_pointer_cast, but I find it kinda ugly and not very maintainable.

I also don't want to add the functionality of `foo()` to the classes `B` and `C`, because those are small independent data structures on which many other classes operate.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT:** In the original post I simplified a bit too much. The new example should clear things up.

Comment: Have you heard of polymorphism?  You can make them virtual member functions and get this behavior.

Comment: Note that the line `a = b;` results in slicing. (There aren't any data members here, but notably this line doesn't make `a` suddenly a `B`.)

Comment: Read up on polymorphism, inheritance, interfaces, virtual functions and pointers to name a few.

Comment: The classes B and C are only for holding data. The method foo should absolutely not be a member of either of those as it doesn't have anything to do with those classes themselves.

Comment: @Pfaeff Sounds like a **visitor pattern**?

Answer (score 1):

Add a pure virtual function `foo()` to your base class and override in subsequent derived classes. Then have your global function `foo()` (which has nothing to do with member functions with the same name) accept a reference to `std::shared_ptr` const as a parameter:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
class A{
public:
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

class B : public A{
public:
    void foo() override{
        std::cout << "Calling foo(B) method!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class C : public A{
public:
    void foo() override{
        std::cout << "Calling foo(C) method!" << std::endl;
    }
};

void foo(const std::shared_ptr<A>& param){
    param->foo();
}

int main(){
    std::shared_ptr<A> b = std::make_shared<B>();
    std::shared_ptr<A> c = std::make_shared<C>();
    foo(b);
    foo(c);
}
```

Comment: Imagine `foo` to be a member function of another class that operates on `B` and `C` type objects. As I have many classes like that, I don't want to add all that functionality to `B` and `C` themselves. The result of `foo()` also depends heavily on the member variables of the implementing class.

Answer (score 0):

[As BoBTFish pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282112/automatic-method-selection-based-on-class-instance#comment77527538_45282112), the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) is a potential solution for this problem:

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

class B;
class C;

class Visitor
{
public:
    virtual void visit(B* b) const = 0;
    virtual void visit(C* b) const = 0;
};

class A
{
public:    
    virtual void bar() const = 0;
    virtual void accept(const Visitor* visitor) = 0;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "B.bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    void accept(const Visitor* visitor) 
    {
        visitor->visit(this);
    }
};

class C : public A
{
public:    
    void bar() const
    {
        std::cout << "C.bar()" << std::endl;
    }

    void accept(const Visitor* visitor) 
    {
        visitor->visit(this);
    }    
};

class Z : public Visitor
{
public:
    Z(int variable) : m_variable(variable) {};

    void visit(B* b) const
    {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(B) method! " << m_variable << std::endl;
        b->bar();
    }

    void visit(C* c) const
    {
        std::cout << "Calling foo(C) method!" << m_variable << std::endl;
        c->bar();
    }
private:
  int m_variable;
};


int main()
{
  std::shared_ptr<A> b(new B());

  Z z(42);

  b->accept(&z);
}
```

http://cpp.sh/2vah5

Thank you very much!